# Windows Store Apps: change the background of GridViewItem on PointerOver

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a gridview thats' bound to the following model

```
    class Item
    {
    string Title;
    string ImagePath
    string ImagePathPressed;
    }
```

where **ImagePath** & **ImagePathPressed** are paths to images within the app.

now I want my grid View Item to change it's background when the mouse is over from the value in **ImagePath** to that in **ImagePathPressed**

how to achive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it

I implemented a control template like this:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" Tag={Binding}>
                        <Border.Resources>
                        <!-- Define brush resources for both states-->
                            <ImageBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush"  ImageSource="{Binding Tag.ImagePathPressed, ElementName=OuterContainer}" Stretch="None" />
                            <ImageBrush x:Key="DefaultBrush"  ImageSource="{Binding Tag.ImagePath, ElementName=OuterContainer}" Stretch="None" />
                        </Border.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent" >
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Tag="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" >
                            <Grid.Background>
                            <!-- Default background-->
                                <ImageBrush x:Name="BGBrush" ImageSource="{Binding Tag.ImagePath, ElementName=ReorderHintContent}" Stretch="None" Opacity="0" />
                            </Grid.Background>
```

I had to set the **Tag** for both the border and the Grid in order to have access to the properties of the model

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you make these variables as properties and also implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** on your class. And on your **mouseOver** event of gridView change the **ImagePath** to that of **ImagePathPressed** it will reflect the change in **ImagePath**.i think on your mouseover event you can get the on which item is your mouse pointer reside.

Answer (score 0):

Following this link to get guideline to implement Style for GridViewItem

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709915.aspx

You should implement your class members as Bindable Properties then implement PointerOver state as guideline in above link.
I suggest that you should create two images (one for normal state and other one for hover state)
For example:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="NormalImage" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                    <Image x:Name="PressImage" Source="{Binding ImagePathPressed}" Opacity="0"/>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PressImage"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 Duration="0"
                                                 To="1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">...
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it in a similar approach, please check my Answer above